# Powershell Background Job - How do I get output from Export-Counter/Get-Counter with 'ComputerName' parameter?

Tags: powershell, performance-testing, background-process

I am trying to collect performance data from a powershell background job while applying 'load' to the system in the foreground.
If I run my Get-Counter/Export-Counter script without a -ComputerName parameter, as a background job, it creates an output file with performance data from the local computer, as expected.

```
# Background job, No ComputerName

$scriptBlockStr = "Get-Counter -Counter ""\Memory\Available MBytes""     -SampleInterval 2 -MaxSamples 3 | Export-Counter -Force -FileFormat CSV -Path $PSScriptRoot\MinPerfTest.csv"
$sb = [scriptblock]::Create($ScriptBlockStr)

$j = Start-Job -Name "PerfMon01" -ScriptBlock $sb
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
Stop-Job $j.Id

Write-Host "See  $PSScriptRoot\MinPerfTest.csv."
```

If I include the -ComputerName parameter, and run the script block in the foreground, it creates the output file with performance data from the specified computer.

```
# Foreground job, With ComputerName

$scriptBlockStr = "Get-Counter -Counter ""\Memory\Available MBytes"" -ComputerName ""\\CPQDEV.fpx.com"" -SampleInterval 2 -MaxSamples 3 | Export-Counter -Force -FileFormat CSV -Path $PSScriptRoot\MinPerfTest.csv"
$sb = [scriptblock]::Create($ScriptBlockStr)

& $sb

Write-Host "See  $PSScriptRoot\MinPerfTest.csv. (Wait! It can take a while.)"
```

But if I run the script with the -ComputerName parameter, as a background job, the Export-Counter cmdlet never produces any output.

```
# Background job, With ComputerName

$scriptBlockStr = "Get-Counter -Counter ""\Memory\Available MBytes"" -ComputerName ""\\CPQDEV.fpx.com"" -SampleInterval 2 -MaxSamples 3 | Export-Counter -Force -FileFormat CSV -Path $PSScriptRoot\MinPerfTest.csv"
$sb = [scriptblock]::Create($ScriptBlockStr)

$j = Start-Job -Name "PerfMon01" -ScriptBlock $sb
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
Stop-Job $j.Id

Write-Host "See  $PSScriptRoot\MinPerfTest.csv. (Wait! It could take a while, if it works at all.)"
```

Can you tell me what I need to do to get performance data from named computers? 
Thank you!

Comment: Does the directory structure exist on the target computer?  It's probably throwing an error.  Try retrieving the job for any output from the job.

Comment: Don't use `Stop-Job`.  [Use `Receive-Job -Wait`.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/receive-job?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: To expand on your suggestion @BaconBits : `$j = Start-Job -Name "PerfMon01" -ScriptBlock $sb | Receive-Job -Wait`

Comment: Background jobs use remoting (even though it's running on the local machine), so you're running into a double-hop issue.  You can use runspaces instead of jobs on the local machine, or use remote jobs instead of local jobs to eliminate the second hop.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 By 'target computer' do you mean where $PSScriptRoot is pointing? Would the background job process be running on a different computer than the foreground Powershell script?

Comment: @mjolinor I don't see any documentation that says what you're suggesting.

Comment: I'd read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_jobs?view=powershell-5.1) for details on running Jobs remotely.

Comment: Use Invoke-Command -AsJob, and run it on the computer you're wanting to monitor.

Comment: I'm confused about where the background job is running. In my third example, is the background job going to run in a different place than the one in my first example (above)?

Comment: In your third example, your job is running on the local computer, but it's trying to initiate a command to a remote PC.  Based on the documentation, it looks like PowerShell doesn't like this as the doc lists alternatives to running remote jobs.

Comment: @mjolinor I'm expecting -ComputerName parameter of Get-Counter will eventually contain a list of 2 - 6 computers. Does the job need to run on all of the computers?

Comment: You want to run get-counter as a background job on each computer you want to monitor. You specify the computer names in Invoke-Command, not in Get-Counter.

Answer (score 1):

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_jobs?view=powershell-5.1)

Your issue is with remote jobs.  Here's an easier suggestion (from msdn):

```
$SB = [ScriptBlock]::Create('Get-Counter -Counter "Memory\Available MBytes" -SampleInterval 2 -MaxSamples 3')
Invoke-Command -ComputerName \\CPQDEV.fpx.com -ScriptBlock $SB -AsJob |
  Receive-Job -Wait |
  Export-Counter -Force -FileFormat CSV -Path "$PSScriptRoot\MinPerfTest.csv"

Write-Host "See  $PSScriptRoot\MinPerfTest.csv. (may not work)"
```